# emacs remove spaces to the edge of the page

Tags: emacs, elisp

I often find myself needing to delete a lot of whitespace to the edge of the page when working in emacs.

How can remove it in a quick keystroke? I looked around in the ["deleting whitespace" emacs lisp wiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace), but did not find what I needed.

Here is an example:

The underscore ( _ ) is the cursor, and the place I want to skip to is the vertical bar ( | ), in my crude representation.

```
somecode...{
      indending
      if(...) {
|         _
       }
}
```

If I were to just repeatedly press backspace it would make my pinky tired, and take awhile. How may I delete it with a quick keystroke, or at the very least an internal function that I could keybind?

Comment: Not exactly by emacs, but one liner `sed -r -i 's/\s+$//g' file2clean.txt` will do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in **help apropos** by typing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and the word `whitespace`. It will list for example

```
delete-trailing-whitespace    M-x ... RET
   Delete trailing whitespace between START and END.
fixup-whitespace          M-x ... RET
   Fixup white space between objects around point.
```

The first deletes trailing whitespace within the current region.
The second does what you want, at point. Click button 2 on the function name to get more info.

Neither probably have a default binding for you, so to execute the second you type <kbd>M-x</kbd> and the first few chars `fixup-` and <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete. 
Add your own binding to a key for ease of use.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do, limiting yourself to commands that have a key binding out of the box, is hitting `M-SPC` (for `just-one-space`), which deletes all the spaces except one, and then you can delete the last one with backspace.